# Asset browser shows assets from a file where a mesh is parented to another

Tags: parent, asset-browser

Blendfile has two objects: A Wine Bottle plus the Wine in it Wine is parented to Bottle. In the viewport when you move the bottle wine moves with it. Not the other way around as expected. Both are set as assets.

But in a new blend scene when I look up these assets in asset browser I see them both. If I use the parent asset (i.e. Bottle) the wine is missing. If I use the child (i.e. wine) it come with the bottle. This is exactly opposite of expectation (child should move with the parent even from the asset browser to current file)

Is this a bug? I am using Blender 4.6LTS